# 'Profile file contained no credentials for profile' error when doing PutItem using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-fargate

I'm trying to put an item into a DynamoDB table using the AWS SDK for Java.

I am using the `EnhancedPutItem.java` [example from the docs](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/EnhancedPutItem.java):

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(region)
            .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
            .build();

        putRecord(enhancedClient) ;
        ddb.close();
    }
...
```

When running locally I can put the item successfully, but when I run my application as a task on Fargate, it throws this error:

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'default': ProfileFile(profilesAndSectionsMap=[]).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error states that the SDK is looking for credentials within the default credential profiles file & cannot find any.

This is because the sample code explicitly specifies a `ProfileCredentialsProvider` as the credentials provider for the `DynamoDbClient`.

This overrides the [default credential provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default), which by default would be looking for credentials in a variety of locations - including the ECS container credentials.

**You need to remove the use of the [`ProfileCredentialsProvider`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html).**

---

You have 2 options:

1. specify no credential provider when creating the client - the SDK will fallback to the default credential provider and then find the ECS container credentials; this is the most common option and will most likely work across various environments (as the chain would look sequentially in multiple places)
2. replace the use of `ProfileCredentialsProvider` with [`ContainerCredentialsProvider`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/ContainerCredentialsProvider.html) instead, which would only specifically look for ECS container credentials

Option 1 is recommended as it is the most common configuration & your code has the highest chance of working across various environments (as the chain would look sequentially for multiple credential providers).

---

To implement option 1, change:

```java
ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
    .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .region(region)
    .build();
```

to:

```
Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
    .region(region)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 looks like this:

```
private AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider =  ContainerCredentialsProvider.builder().build();

private final DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
        .region(Region.of(REGION))
        .build();
```